# Struts2 conversion warning

Tags: validation, error-handling, struts2, type-conversion, ognl

I am developing a model based web application on Struts2.2.3. What I mean by model is, database tables are represented as java classes(you know). And models have properties with types such as Integer, Date and so on. When I render these values on page, and when user puts values other than it is original type, it always giving me exceptions. It is not reaching validation function before getting populated.

And it shows following message on page:

```
Invalid field value for field "estimates[1].count".
```

Also shows following exception on console

```
 WARN OgnlValueStack:60 - Error setting expression 'estimates[1].count' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@a61ffd'
```

I saw several people had this issue before like this: 
http://osdir.com/ml/user-struts.apache.org/2009-12/msg00037.html

I have my ConversionError interceptor removed from my default stack. And my devMode is off. However, I am still getting these errors.

**UPDATE:**

I found that error exception can be caught by MyAction-validation.xml and error message can be customized. But OGNL warning still remained.

Thus the question is:

Is there any way not to show this warning on log?

Comment: please show us some code, an example of an action this is happening with and that actions xml (if any is used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encountered this, there is no solution not to display this WARN on console or log:

Please read:

http://www.mail-archive.com/user@struts.apache.org/msg90542.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the framework is trying to convert your form data to an inadequate Java type (Generally into a String).
So if your beans or actions have different types a conversion error is thrown.

I fix this by creating my own personal converters and register them in the xwork-conversion.properties file.

You should check this out: 
http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/type-conversion.html

Comment: Hi. Is there any way to not display  WARN OgnlValueStack:60 on console. Because it shows this exception when my custom converter throw TypeConversionException. I removed error message by setting Conversion validator on my Action-validation.xml

Comment: What I do is set the log level to ERROR for OGNL and related classes and/or packages